# Fdisk doesn't recognize Macbook's file system

Tags: macos, filesystems, fdisk, forensics

I need to mirror a MacBook, which was functioning properly. But when I ran fdisk -l, I got this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 113 GiB, 121332826112 bytes, 236978176 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 867EBE6B-3FFA-4314-A037-3969B1EC7865

Device      Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1      40    409639    409600   200M EFI System
/dev/sda2  409640 236978135 236568496 112,8G unknown
```

Due to the OS (Caine Linux) not recognizing the file system, I cannot mount the partition and see the data inside. I used Guymager to extract /dev/sda as a whole (I guess dd would have done the job as well), but why cannot I mount /dev/sda2 and see the data inside? Is every MacOS like this as well?

Comment: If your OS doesn't understand the disk format, it's not surprising. Try it from another Mac, then at least you could check whether it's HFS+ or APFS.... & yes, every macOS disk is like this, so is every Windows disk, or unix disk... each has their preferred scheme, your own OS needs to be able to recognise it & read/write as appropriate.

Comment: Since it's an SSD, I believe it's APFS... Linux support of it is still on development

Comment: That's a complete guess. It could be either. It could also be anything else, though one would assume that would be recognised accurately.